# Consume RequestBody in Rest Controller Lazily in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I own a Spring boot Rest API which is consumed by many external Applications. This API receives a List of documents(base64 String) in one request. Each document is of around 100MB and most of the time there are 6,7 documents in Request payload. Let's say if 7 documents are in list it will consume 700MB in memory which is too much. I want to make it memory efficient.
I Can't ask Consumer of API to send document one by one, I have to receive them at once in a request but i want load documents one by one in memory instead of loading at once.
Here is example.

```
  @PostMapping("/documents")
      Employee newEmployee(@RequestBody List<String> DocuemntsInBase64) {
      }
```

Also let me know if [JsonSurfer](https://github.com/jsurfer/JsonSurfer) can help in rescue.

Comment: Don't use `@RequestBody` and read the content of the request yourself manually.

Comment: @M.Deinum How? Please write an example here. Please also explain how payload will be loading as stream in memory

Comment: You can get the plain request by adding `HttpServletRequest request` to the method parameters (remove the `@RequestBody List<String> DocuemntsInBase64`) . From there you can access the request data.

Comment: Will it be consuming less memory?

Comment: Probably not. If you receive 700 MB worth of data in one request, the server has to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i have solve this mystery simply by using HttpServletRequest and [JsonSurfer](https://github.com/jsurfer/JsonSurfer) Library.
Here a sample code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postDocuments",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = {"application/json", "application/xml"},
            produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void createHotel(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        JsonSurfer surfer = JsonSurferJackson.INSTANCE;

        try {
            surfer.configBuilder()
                    .bind("Your JsonPath of list", new JsonPathListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onValue(Object value, ParsingContext context) {
                            logger.info("Document of size: "+value.toString().getBytes().length);
                        }
                    })
                    .buildAndSurf(request.getReader());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```